# Assets retrieving issue in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, domain-driven-design

**Issue**: Assets retrieving issue in Laravel 5.4

Server root directory

```
-- public_html/
-- pilardir/ [Laravel Installed Here Project Controller, Models, Views Working from this directory]
```

Domain setup

```
www.thepiresearch.com    Domain pointing directory (public_html/)
```

The problem here is the laravel application setup in the [pilardir] directory so when we setting up any assets file or upload blog images from the app then its uploading here pilardir/public/uploads/blogs which is all correct.

Now the problem is when we fetching the assets files / images it return the path and assets url from

```
public_html/public/uploads/blogs
```

which is incorrect.

Comment: is your project running on Cpanel?

Comment: Yes the site is on hostgator

Comment: as of Laravel principle, Laravel stores to type file, static in the public folder, and the dynamic file is stored in storage folder, for the Cpanel, if your assets are in the public folder you need some configuration as follow
1: move all laravel project files (but not public) out from the public_html folder and then need to change your code of file index.php file in the public folder and point to the bootstrap.php file

Comment: But there nothing in the public_html folder

Comment: so where is your project located in cpanel?

Comment: The problem here is the laravel application setup in the [pilardir] directory so when we setting up any assets file or upload blog images from the app then its uploading here pilardir/public/uploads/blogs which is all correct.

Pleaase read my question carefully

Answer (score 0):

please try this :
[www.thepiresearch.com/uploads/blogs](http://www.thepiresearch.com/uploads/blogs)

remove public and public_html of  public_html/public/uploads/blogs

Comment: You know how the laravel dir working ????

Comment: did you test ????

Comment: There no point to test it but i test it no response. Nothing wrong in the assets url the error in the pointing url have you understand the problem